# How to plot a 3D heatmap or histogram over an image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, heatmap, contour, surface

I have this  type of data:

```
Data = [1:1:9; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ;1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9;1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
```

Where the first entry is the zone of interest (9 zones total) and the remaining 4 array entries are how long something stayed in the zone (just arbitrary now for this question.

I want to plot how long each thing is in each zone on a picture of a map as a 3d "heatmap" style plot. The map is divided into a 3x3 grid like so:

```
1 2 3 

4 5 6

7 8 9
```

How do I plot this? I have tried the contour and surf functions but I am not sure how I would map them to the grid. I would like to overlay the graph on a map picture as my final step but just getting the graph up and running would be great!

Comment: how would you like to show the 4 different things (lets call them A to D)? 4 subplot where each has a heatmap, or the sum of them or a 3D view with stacked floating surfaces or any other specfic idea?

Comment: @Finn Ideally both just to visualize what they look like. So where A frequented and then a summary graph of where the major hotspots were overall for every A-D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `imagesc`for the 2D version or `bar3` for the 3D version, in this example I created some subplots, but of course you are free to change this option.

```
Data = [1:1:9; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ;1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9;1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];

M = zeros(3,3);
```

**2D**

```
for ii = 2:size(Data,1)
    subplot(2,2,ii-1)
    M(1:end) = Data(ii,:);
    imagesc(M)
    colormap jet
    shading flat %for an exact result
    % shading interp %for a smooth result 
end

figure
```

**3D** (even if I think that the 3D view is useless)

```
for ii = 2:size(Data,1)
        subplot(2,2,ii-1)
        M(1:end) = Data(ii,:);
        h{ii} = bar3(M)
        colorbar
    for k = 1:length(h{ii})
        zdata = h{ii}(k).ZData;
        h{ii}(k).CData = zdata;
        h{ii}(k).FaceColor = 'interp';
    end
end
```

Comment: What's the b in length(b)?

Comment: That was my mistake, so now `length(h{ii})` corresponds to the number of elements that compose the 3D heatmap.

Comment: The 2D version works, but the 3d gives an error on line: zdata = h{ii}(k).ZData; improper index matrix reference. Also is there a way in the 2D version to overlay the grid number on the plot? sort of like this: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consciousness-representational/NumberedGrid1.jpg. The reason that I like the 3d is because I want to plot those over a picture of a building. that shows where everything was over the observation period.

Comment: is there a way to plot the 2d grid into a png image I have? basically plot the heatmap into the floor plan it is referring to? the png is grayscale.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the kind of plot that you want, but you could use Delaunay Triangulation to map your duration data as a surface over your grid points. The MatLab file exchange has a nice function for mapping something using this method.

[Making Surface Plots from Scatter Data](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5105-making-surface-plots-from-scatter-data/content/surf_from_scatter.m)

Comment: That doesn't look exactly like what I need. My main issue is I don't know how to make it plot to the 3x3 grid I have. It just puts 1-9 on the axis and plots along it, I need it to put 1-3, 4-6, 7-9 on separate sections of the figure and then plot at each of those locations.